# Autorun JavaFX Application (Raspbian)

Tags: raspbian, javafx

I am trying to autrun my JavaFX application right after booting. The Application works fine when executing it by "java -jar Application.jar".

I have tried many different ways to autorun my application and it seems like it does run, but there is no GUI. I only see the normal desktop but I am unable to move my cursor or clicking anything else. The only way I can stop the application is to kill it over SSH.

I hope someone has a solution for me...